# Is there any alternative to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() since this method is deprecrated in API level 29

Tags: android

I am using Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory to get the external storage directory path (/storage/emulated/0) inside my application. Since this method is deprecated in API level 29, is there any alternative way to get the external storage directory ?

I have looked into the docs but wasn't able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

You just can use it as it works.

But how to use it if you have no read or write access? What are your plans?

Better use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to get path to one of the public directories on external storage.

Use it. Its no longer deprecated and works.

Comment: Event getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is deprecated in API level 29

Comment: Not anymore i wrote.